# Wordpress: Working with functions.php and foreach loop

Tags: php, wordpress

Why if I call a custom function from within functions.php it does not work?

My custom function:

```
function get_cat_slug($ID) {
    $post_id = (int) $ID;
    $category = &get_category($post_id);
    echo $category->slug;
}
```

Loop trough all posts, like that:

```
$args = array(
 'numberposts' => -1
);  
$posts = get_posts($args);
foreach ($posts as $post){
   // and withing this lopp I would like to get a category slug
   // so I am calling my custom function, also included in functions.php
   get_cat_slug($post->ID);

}
```

But, `get_cat_slug($post->ID)` always return `null`. Why? What am I missing?
Any suggestions much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should definitely not be an ampersand before get_category, which actually needs [a Category ID and not a post ID](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category).) 

[get_the_category](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category) returns an array of categories (because posts can have multiple), and you also do not need to specify (int). If you only want to echo the slug of the first cat (assuming single categorization,) try:

```
function get_cat_slug($post_id) {
  $cat_id = get_the_category($post_id);
  $category = get_category($cat_id[0]);
  echo $category->slug;
}
```

Following wordpress function styles, though, if you're naming your function with `get_...`, it should `return $category->slug` rather than `echo` it, meaning you'd have to `echo get_cat_slug($post->ID);` in your template loop.

Your loop depends on a WP_Query, which belongs in a template file and not functions.php. Which template file depends on what purpose your loop is serving and where you would like to display it. index.php is the logical choice for a primary post loop, though archive.php, single.php, or any pre-existing theme-specific template might make sense, as would any custom, non-standard template you create.

Comment: After the change, my function still return null. How to check if the function is being call at all?

Comment: Where are you running your loop? You should check if you're actually passing a valid post id in the get_cat_slug call. `echo $post->ID` before you call the get_cat_slug function.

Comment: If you're seeing null output, the function is being called

Comment: Also, you need to run the loop in your template file (index.php, probably). It will not work in functions.php

Comment: Yes. Why this will not work within functions.php? Even I have this within foreach loop?

Comment: It's just not what functions.php is for: http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop#Using_The_Loop

Comment: Would you recommend putting the foreach loop function inside template file? Or creating completely independent files?

Answer (score 1):

May be your cast should be

```
$post_id = intval($ID);
```

[ref](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php)

Have you tried to log every step? So you can exactly see where it goes wrong